# How to force the data-layer to throw exception during DELETE SQL statement?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a method that deletes a row from a table. I am writing the unit tests for it. One of the test cases has to cause an error condition on delete to test the catch of the try/catch block. I cannot for the life of me think of how to cause an error to catch. ADO, EF... anything will do.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the code here?

Comment: Are you writing unit tests or integration tests?

Comment: What unit test framework are you using?

Answer (score 2):

> I have a method that deletes a row from a table. I am writing the unit
>   tests for it.

Unless that method actually contains something testable, you may be spending time just to exercise framework functionality. There's nothing wrong with that as part of an integration test, but it may not make a very good unit test.

Let's assume there *is* something in the method to unit test. A clean way of isolating that functionality is to inject mocks of the dependencies into the class being tested.

In this case, it sounds like the dependency would be ADO.Net and/or EF. One of those mocks could be configured to throw an exception.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;

    public MyClass( IRepository repository )
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public void DoSomethingThatMightThrow()
    {
        // some logic that you want to test

        // this might throw
        var obj = _repository.Delete( 123 );

        // some logic that you want to test
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void ATest()
{
    // uses Moq framework, but any mocking framework should do this

    var repository = new Mock<IRepository>();
    repository.Setup( o => o.Delete( It.IsAny<int>() ) ).Throws( new DataException() );

    var obj = new MyClass( repository );
    obj.DoSomethingThatMightThrow();
}
```

---

I'm currently reading [The Art of Unit Testing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617290890), which discusses how to identify good units. The author asserts that a test doesn't have to map to a single method, but tests should isolate logical units and be easily repeatable. A dependency on a database in a unit test is rarely a good idea (again data access can be part of a great integration test).

Answer (score 1):

First: try to mock it as TimMedora has shown.

But, in case you cannot, you can work it around in many ways, but it will take some time, code, and will not always be possible, depending on your DB engine, DB structure, DB contents, etc, etc.

Try to use any means unrelated to queries! DB engines usually has tons of extra features that can cause an error during queries!

For example:

- create new user account on the DB
- add all typical permissions for that account EXCEPT for the DELETE on that table
- change that one specific test's setup to login as that user

Result: Trying to delete any row will be aborted, since required permissions are not granted.

Another example:

- create a dummy table `RowLock(id int)`
- add constraint on that column to be `foreign key` that targets the TestedTable's PrimaryKey
- add one row to the RowLock table, with ID equal to a some row from the TestedTable

Result: Now you will be able to delete any row in the TestedTable, except that marked one by the RowLock, and trying to delete that marked one will abort because of the FK constraint.

You can even alter the test's setup to perform the extra changes (add user, add RowLock table, etc) and then clean it up after the test during teardown (remove user, remove RowLock table, etc).. But as I said, it all costs significant work.

I don't recommend such approaches as they are very limited (rowlock is delete/update only, permissions are only per-database, per-table or per-column, etc). But still they are a good last-resort option, as they have the advantage of being almost always possible - like RowLock which simply requires the DB to support checked FKs constraints.

Comment: Ok, both of you. Thanks for your answers. You have given me much to chew on, which is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Ok helpful people. I really want to understand this mocking framework.  The unit I am trying to test is:

Comment: @user2919960: your comment got trimmed..?